# Context-free grammar of the concatenation of a string S and subsequence of reversed S

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I have to find a Context-Free grammar that generates the language:

$L_1 = \{x\#y\ |\ y$ is a subsequence of $x^R$, and $x\in\{a,b\}^*\}$, $\Sigma=\{a,b,\#\}$

---

The concatenation of two mutually reversed strings are pretty simple, but I just can't figure out how to express "plugging in random terminals in $x$" so that $x^R$ could contain $y$ as its subsequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start with a grammar for the language of words of the form $x\#x^R$:
$$
S \to aSa \mid bSb \mid \#
$$
This is our starting point. Now there are two interpretations of the term *subsequence*. Under the first interpretation, a subsequence is obtained by removing any number of symbols. This just means that we can omit the second side of each production of the form $S \to \sigma S \sigma$, resulting in the grammar
$$
S \to aSa \mid bSb \mid aS \mid bS \mid \#
$$
Under the second interpretation, the subsequence must be contiguous. Each derivation should therefore be in three steps: first only on the left side, then on both sides, then finally again only on the left side. This requires three nonterminals, and results in the following grammar:
$$
S \to aS \mid bS \mid T \\
T \to aTa \mid bTb \mid U \\
U \to aU \mid bU \mid \#
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about the definition of the word *subsequence* has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97122/discussion-on-answer-by-yuval-filmus-context-free-grammar-of-the-concatenation-o).

Answer (score 3):

"Plugging in random terminals in $x$" is the right approach.

To implement that, we need to understand clearly how we have achieved "the concatenation of two mutually reversed strings" first. It is done by growing a string from both ends with the same symbol repeatedly, a characteristic technique for context-free grammar, as illustrated below.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&\#&\\
&a\#a&\\
&ba\#ab&\\
&bba\#abb\\
&abba\#abba\\
&babba\#abbab
\end{array}$$

To plugging in random terminals on the left hand side, we can grow the left hand side without growing the right hand side.

Starting from $\#$, we will either add the same symbol to both side, or add a symbol to the left hand side only. Hence the following simple grammar.

$$S\to\#\mid aSa\mid bSb\mid aS\mid bS$$

Here is an easy exercise.

**Exercise.** find a context-free grammar that generates this language,
$\{xy\mid x,y\in\{a,b\}^*$ $\text{where }x$ $\text{with some }$$a\text{'s removed is the same as}$ $y\text{ with some}$ $b\text{'s removed}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd approach this:

- Make a grammar that can produce palindromes
- Make a grammar that can produce "any sequence of `a`s and `b`s followed by `#`"
- Make a grammar that can produce "any sequence of `a`s and `b`s"

Then combine the three. $L_1$ is:

- Any sequence of `a`s and `b`s
- The first half of a palindrome
- Any sequence of `a`s and `b`s followed by `#`
- The second half of the palindrome

Giving something like this:

```
S → G P ; gibberish, followed by modified palindrome

P → a P a ; standard palindrome grammar
P → b P b
P → G # ; but instead of ∅ in its center, it has gibberish followed by #

G → a G ; produces any sequence of a's and b's
G → b G
G → ∅
```

(There are a few different notations for CFGs, so in case this isn't the one you're used to: `S` is always the starting symbol, `∅` means the empty string, and everything after a `;` is a "comment" that doesn't affect the grammar.)

EDIT: It's been pointed out that you want a reversed *subsequence*, not a reversed *substring*. But this is easy to fix: just allow adding arbitrary gibberish on the left side of the "palindrome" part.

```
P → G P
```

You can then simplify the starting rule:

```
S → P
```

Everything else should remain the same.

Comment: "Subsequence" usually means "a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some or no elements without changing the order of the remaining elements." (Quote taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).)

Comment: @rici Ah, I read "substring"! My bad, I'll correct my grammar.